# Specify valid default value for [disabled] property on AMP page amp-bind

Tags: html, amp-html

When using amp-bind, I'm receiving the following error:

```
Default value for <input [disabled]="ampState.success"> does not match
first result (). We recommend writing expressions with matching
default  values, but this can be safely ignored if intentional.
```

My initial states are:

```
  <amp-state id="ampState">
    <script type="application/json">
      {
        // ...
        "success": "",
      }
    </script>
  </amp-state>
```

And the offending element is:

```
<input type="submit" <!-- .... --> [disabled]="ampState.success" />
```

Is there anyway to remove this warning, consdering I *can't* provide a default value for `[disabled]` without it actually disabling the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this warning can be avoided by setting the state as follows:

```
  <amp-state id="ampState">
    <script type="application/json">
      {
        // ...
        "success": "",
      }
    </script>
  </amp-state>
```

As the AMP validator looks for `actualValue === expectedValue` where the disabled properties initial actualValue is actually `false`, not `''`